# How to open next window in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am new to Java.

My concern is, I have created login page, On successful login I could not open the new window which is 'contact' window.

My Login page  related code,

Import statements,

```
package contact;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

On successful login My code is,

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you are ssuccessfully logged in");

           mainframe m = new mainframe();
           m.setVisible(true);
```

My mainfrme class has acually have GUI,

package contact;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class mainframe extends javax.swing.JPanel {

```
/**
 * Creates new form mainframe
 */
public mainframe() {
    initComponents();

}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Please help me, I am ready to provide  you information and modify above code...Thanks[image]

Comment: on which condition you are opening this window. some more details about login.

Comment: The code you're showing seems to be fully autogenerated. I suggest you read the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and the other tutorials. GUI builders seem like fun because they're quick and easy, but now that it stopped helping you have no idea what to do.

Comment: How about showing some action listener code.

Comment: It is already added, and My successful login code I have shown...so please tell me what to do ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mainframe` is a `JPanel` that hasn't been added to a container. Calling `setVisible()` on it is useless, because it won't be displayable unless it's in a container such as a `JFrame`.

Comment: That wouldn't be very useful. You've already got the GUI builder creating your user interface. If I write the rest of the code, that doesn't make **you** the programmer. I linked you the Swing tutorial, everything's explained there.

Comment: pLEASE GIVE ME SOME SWING TUTORIAL

Comment: @ArpitParekh I linked it in my first comment on your post. It's the blue colored link named "Swing Tutorial".